# Zooms out unexpectedly in Power BI

Tags: power-bi

I have a project going on like this:

[image]

Mostly everything works fine, but when I filter on a certain location that I have logged for two years and therefore looks like this:
[image]
[image]

But when it's filtered to those locations that has "two records" it suddenly zooms all the way out:

[image]

I have tried changing the location or name of area slightly to see if that helps but apparently not. I think I must only allow single select for years which helps with this, but ideally the user should be able to see all years.

Do you know what's going on or any ideas on how I can avoid this sudden zoom out?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your zoom code, but without seeing the code and the data it is impossible to say for sure